# SetInterval in for Loop executing only last time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a little problem with SetInterval in javascript.  I have a component which load content from url to div. The problem lies in the undefined number of these components.

Each have individual url and reload time.

and the PROBLEM is that my setinterval will execute only the last of components in the **for loop**.

I NEED to each component reloading on it self. :
component n1 = reload time 5s
component n2= reload time 60sec.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var pocet = $('[id^=komponenta]').length;
  var i;

  for (i = 0, text = ""; i < pocet; i++) {

    var nazev = 'komponenta' + i;
    var cil = 'target' + i;
    var adresa = document.getElementById(nazev).adresa.value;
    var cas = document.getElementById(nazev).reload.value;

    setInterval(function() {
      $('#' + cil).load(adresa);
    }, cas);

  }

});
```

```html
<div id="target0"></div>
<div id="target1"></div>
<div id="target2"></div>


<form class="pure-form pure-form-stacked" method="POST" id="komponenta0">
  <fieldset>

    <label for="email">Komponenta:</label>

    <label for="remember" class="pure-checkbox">
    </label>
    <input type="hidden" name="adresa" id="adresa" type="text" placeholder="Vložte prosím URL" value="text.html">
    <input type="hidden" name="reload" value="10000">

  </fieldset>
</form>

<form class="pure-form pure-form-stacked" method="POST" id="komponenta1">
  <fieldset>

    <label for="email">Komponenta:</label>


    <label for="remember" class="pure-checkbox">
    </label>
    <input type="hidden" name="adresa" id="adresa" type="text" placeholder="Vložte prosím URL" value="text2.html">
    <input type="hidden" name="reload" value="2000">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: It's a scope issue, as every component use the same cli, you should create a function an pass the cli, so that function can keep the specific cli and not changed by others. And the adresa.

Comment: Any ideas how to do it ? Im a mere beginner with javascript

Comment: I think [Jaromanda X](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x) has already post a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
(function(CIL, ADRESA, CAS) {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#' + CIL).load(ADRESA);
  }, CAS);
}(cil, adresa, cas));
```

i,e, wrap your setInterval as above

this is also valid, but may be a little less obvious

```
(function(cil, adresa, cas) {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#' + cil).load(adresa);
  }, cas);
}(cil, adresa, cas));
```

P.S. as @fuyushimoya stated - it's a scope issue

Comment: I like this idea, as my first though is use `.bind`, but this should be more browser compatible.

Comment: Holy moly, i get it now. Thanks you a lot !! :)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, it's a scope issue - your setInterval-ed function is called not when the loop is iterating, but after it's through, and only the latest vars are available.

Try this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/93f2athx/) - I replaced your 'load()' with a logging function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    log('loaded');
    var pocet = $('[id^=komponenta]').length;
    var i;

    for (i = 0, text = ""; i < pocet; i++) {
        log(i);

        (function (j) {
            var nazev = 'komponenta' + j;
            var cil = 'target' + j;
            var adresa = document.getElementById(nazev).adresa.value;
            var cas = document.getElementById(nazev).reload.value;
            setInterval(function () {
                log(nazev);
            }, cas);
        }(i));
    }

});

function log(msg) {
    $('.log').append(msg + '<br/>');
}
```